# Как поменять размеры элементов при развертывании окна?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть такая программа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему MenuBar "обрезан", то есть не растягивается на весь размер окна? Вот мой код:

```
   public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


private Button addDataInTableButton;
private Button deleteDataFromTableButton;
private Button clearTableButton;
private Button extrapolationButton;

private TableView<PointOfGraphic> tableView;
private LineChart mainChart;
private HBox mainLayout;
private Button approximationButton;
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {


    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setTop(createMenuBar());


    tableView = createTableView();
    // Кнопки управленя таблицей и графиком
    addDataInTableButton = new Button("Добавить точку");
    deleteDataFromTableButton = new Button("Удалить точку");
    clearTableButton = new Button("Очистить таблицу");
    addDataInTableButton.setOnAction(this);
    deleteDataFromTableButton.setOnAction(this);
    clearTableButton.setOnAction(this);
    approximationButton = new Button("Аппроксимировать");
    approximationButton.setOnAction(this);
    extrapolationButton = new Button("Экстраполировать");
    extrapolationButton.setOnAction(this);

    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(addDataInTableButton, deleteDataFromTableButton, clearTableButton);
    mainLayout = new HBox();
    mainLayout.getChildren().add(vBox);

    vBox.getChildren().add(pane);
    vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);
    vBox.getChildren().add(hBox);

    vBox.getChildren().addAll(approximationButton, extrapolationButton);

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout, stage.getMaxWidth(), stage.getHeight());
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("charts.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();


}
 private MenuBar createMenuBar (){

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

    Menu fileMenu = new Menu("Файл");

    MenuItem loadDaraItem = new MenuItem("Импорт данных");
    MenuItem exportDataItem = new MenuItem("Вывести данные на форму HTML");
    MenuItem printItem = new MenuItem("Печать");
    fileMenu.getItems().addAll(loadDaraItem, exportDataItem, printItem);

    Menu editMenu  = new Menu("Работа с таблицей");


    MenuItem addPointItem = new MenuItem("Добавить точку");
    MenuItem deletePointItem = new MenuItem("Удалить точку");
    MenuItem clearTableItem = new MenuItem("Очистить таблицу");
    editMenu.getItems().addAll(addPointItem, deletePointItem, clearTableItem);

    Menu helpMenu = new Menu ("Справка");

    MenuItem helpItem = new MenuItem("Начинающим");
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("О программе");
    helpMenu.getItems().addAll(helpItem, aboutItem);

    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, editMenu, helpMenu);

    return menuBar;

}
```

Как растянуть элементы MenuBar на всю ширину сцены?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `SceneBuilder` для построения интерфейса

Comment: @Tsyklop хотелось бы работать с интерфейсом через программный код

Comment: Ясно. удачи. Хз кто будет вчитываться в код.

Comment: @Tsyklop в любом случае scene builder так же сгенерит код, только это будет xml с кучей аттрибутов, которые могут быть не нужны

Comment: @AndrewBystrov То что не нужно он не генерирует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [setHgrow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#getHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-):

```
mainLayout.setHgrow(vBox, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам лучше пользоваться BorderPane’ом. Он подходит больше для Вашего случая. У BorderPane есть методы setTop(), setCenter(), setRight(), setLeft(), setBottom(). Например, чтобы добавить menuBar в верхнюю часть сцены Вам необходимы вызвать `borderPane.setTop(menuBar)`, и menuBar автоматически добавится и растянется по ширине сцены. 
Таким образом можно добавлять sideBar’ы в левую или правую часть сцены, statusBar или footer в нижнюю часть, а сам контент в центре. Очень удобная штука.